# Crossover require in NodeJS - result empty object

Tags: node.js, require

I have two files with differents functions in a NodeJS program, and each files require the other file to get function inside.
On the seond file included by require, the required element is empty.

**On index.js**

```
const bar = require('./bar.js');
const foo = require('./foo.js');
foo.sayHello();
```

**On foo.js**

```
const bar = require('./bar.js');
var sayHello = function(){
    var name = bar.getName();
    console.log('Hello '+name);
}
module.exports = {
    sayHello : sayHello
}
```

**On bar.js**

```
const foo = require('./foo.js');
var getName = function(){
    return 'Paul';
}
module.exports = {
    getName : getName
}
```

When we lauch this code, the error bellow is displyed :

> *TypeError: bar.getName is not a function*

And if I make a `console.log(bar);` in **foo.js**, the result is an empty object *{}*

To solve this problem we can include the **foo.js** file first, but in this case, it is the **foo** object in the **bar.js** file that will be empty.

Is it impossible to make crossover required with two files?

Comment: You have a circular reference where `bar` loads `foo` and `foo` loads `bar`.  You can't do that.  That causes the module to end up as an empty object.  Break common code into a third shared module that each can load so they aren't loading each other.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understand. It's a shame that it doesn't cause an error on launch, rather than getting an empty object ...

Comment: It is odd that they didn't make it throw.  Not sure why they would ever think it was OK to proceed.